# How to use regex to extract such url

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Here is a text:

```html
<a class="mkapp-btn mab-download"  href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="zhytools.downloadApp('C100306099', 'appdetail_dl', '24', 'http:&#x2F;&#x2F;appdlc.hicloud.com&#x2F;dl&#x2F;appdl&#x2F;application&#x2F;apk&#x2F;f4&#x2F;f44d320c2c1b466389e6f6b3d3f5cff4&#x2F;com.uniquestudio.android.iemoji.1806141014.apk?sign=portal@portal1531621480529&amp;source=portalsite' , 'v1.1.4');">
```

I want to extract

`http:&#x2F;&#x2F;appdlc.hicloud.com&#x2F;dl&#x2F;appdl&#x2F;application&#x2F;apk&#x2F;f4&#x2F;f44d320c2c1b466389e6f6b3d3f5cff4&#x2F;com.uniquestudio.android.iemoji.1806141014.apk?sign=portal@portal1531621480529&amp;source=portalsite`

I use below code to extract it.

```
m = re.search("mkapp-btn mab-download.*'http:&#x2F;&#x2F;[^']'", apk_page)
```

In my opinion, I can use `.*` to match the string between `mkapp-btn mab-download` and `http`. However I failed.

## EDIT

I also tried.

```
m = re.search("(?<=mkapp-btn mab-download.*)http:&#x2F;&#x2F;[^']'", apk_page)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `+` after exclusion (`[^']`) because is more than one character. Also, you need to group using parenthesis to extract only the part you want.

```
m = re.search("mkapp-btn mab-download.*'(http[^']+)'", apk_page)
m.groups()
```

And the output will be

```
('http:&#x2F;&#x2F;appdlc.hicloud.com&#x2F;dl&#x2F;appdl&#x2F;application&#x2F;apk&#x2F;f4&#x2F;f44d320c2c1b466389e6f6b3d3f5cff4&#x2F;com.uniquestudio.android.iemoji.1806141014.apk?sign=portal@portal1531621480529&amp;source=portalsite',)
```